# How to use play framework FakeApplication() for multiple tests?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I would like to use a FakeApplication for testing WS calls, currently I have it like this:

```
class ExampleServiceSpec extends WordSpec with BeforeAndAfter {

private val client = new GenericGrafanaService

"Service" should {
    "post some json" in {
        Play.start(fakeApp)
        assertResult("OK") {
            Await.result(client.postSomeJson("key1", "string2"), Duration.Inf)
        }
        Play.stop(fakeApp)
    }

    "delete some json" in {
        Play.start(fakeApp)
        assertResult("OK") {
            Await.result(client.deleteSomeJson("key1"), Duration.Inf)
        }
        Play.stop(fakeApp)
    }
}
}
```

and the first test passes, but for the next one I get a an exception like this:

```
[info]   java.io.IOException: Closed
[info]   at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.sendRequest(NettyRequestSender.java:96)
[info]   at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:87)
[info]   at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:506)
[info]   at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient.executeRequest(NingWS.scala:47)
[info]   at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSRequest.execute(NingWS.scala:306)
[info]   at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSRequest.execute(NingWS.scala:128)
[info]   at play.api.libs.ws.WSRequest$class.delete(WS.scala:500)
[info]   at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSRequest.delete(NingWS.scala:81)
[info]   at de.zalando.steerage.abdiff.grafana.interface.ExampleService$$anonfun$deleteSomeJson$1.apply(ExampleService.scala:58)
[info]   at de.zalando.steerage.abdiff.grafana.interface.ExampleService$$anonfun$deleteSomeJson$1.apply(ExampleService.scala:56)
[info]   ...
```

I get the same exception even if I change the order of the tests. I also tried repeating the first test twice (same call) and it fails again for the second one. I also tried starting and stopping the `fakeApp` with `before{}` and `after{}`, but I get the same result. I am using play 2.4.

Anyone have an idea how I could adapt my code?

Comment: If you start the application before all tests, and stop it after all tests - will it be a valid solution for you?

Comment: @Tomer yes, that was what I was trying to do, but i turns out I was doing it wrong. First I tried with `before` and `after` but it turns out I should've been using `beforeAll` and `afterAll`.

Comment: This would have been my suggestion..:) glad you found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this by using `beforeAll` and `afterAll`.

```
class TestSpec extends WordSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll { 

    override def beforeAll {
        Play.start(fakeApp)
    }

    ...

    override def afterAll {
        Play.stop(fakeApp)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest

> Sometimes you want to test with the real HTTP stack. If all tests in your test class can reuse the same server instance, you can mix in OneServerPerSuite (which will also provide a new FakeApplication for the suite)

eg:

```
class ExampleServiceSpec extends WordSpec with BeforeAndAfter {

  private val client = new GenericGrafanaService

  "Service" should {
     "post some json" in {
        assertResult("OK") {
         Await.result(client.postSomeJson("key1", "string2"), Duration.Inf)
       }
     }

     "delete some json" in {
       assertResult("OK") {
         Await.result(client.deleteSomeJson("key1"), Duration.Inf)
       }
     }
  }
}
```